# Evaluate the $\iint_S (x^2+y^2) \,dS$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to evaluate $\iint_S (x^2+y^2) \,dS$ where $S$ is the the portion of the sphere $x^2=y^2+z^2=4$ above $z=1$. Apologies for the formatting errors

When I let $z=1, x^2+y^2=3$.
So far I have:

$$SS (x^2+y^2)sqrt(x^2/4-x^2-y^2)+(y^2/4-x^-y^2)+1dA$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection of the plane $z = 1$ and the sphere gives bounds for $\phi$; namely $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

$(1)$ Parametrize the sphere: $G(\theta, \phi) = (2 \cos \theta \sin \phi, 2 \sin \theta \sin \phi, 2 \cos \phi)$

$(2)$ You domain is given by $D = \{(\theta, \phi): 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi, 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\}$

$(3)$ Recall that $n(\theta, \phi) = 4 \sin \phi \cdot \textbf{e}_r$ where $\textbf{e}_r$ is the unit radial vector.

This should be enough to finish the problem.